# Python unpack problem

Tags: python

I have:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f[50], g = unpack('BBBBH50cH', data)
```

The problem is

```
f[50] (too many values to unpack)
```

How do I do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think by `f[50]` you are trying to denote "a list of 50 elements"?

In Python 3.x you can do `a, b, c, d, e, *f, g` to indicate that you want `f` to contain all the values that don't fit anywhere else (see [this PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)).

In Python 2.x, you will need to write it out explicitly:

```
x = unpack(...)
a, b, c, d, e = x[:5]
f = x[5:55]
<etc>
```

Comment: +1. Good to see that Python 3 finally supports this syntax, time to relearn a language.

Comment: Thank you. Sad that some libraries not ported to 3

Comment: @Jonathan: indeed, although more and more are moving over.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `50c` part of the unpack. This is reading 50 characters from the buffer, and returning this as 50 seperate values. If you change it to

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = unpack('BBBBH50sH', data)
```

`f` will be a list of 50 characters read from the buffer, which is what I suspect you want.